# MaskEdittext Cursor issue

Tags: android

I am using MaskEdittext text for formatting a number in US Format (123) 456-7890.I am facing one issue when I type number in edittext and place a cursor on ediittext it will be appeared like this

here is the screen:
[image]

here is my xml code:

```
<com.sample.activities.MaskedEditText
      android:id="@+id/edttextlogin"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="40dp"
      android:background="@drawable/register_rectange1"
      android:hint="@string/phone_number"
      android:imeOptions="actionNext"
      android:inputType="phone"
      android:nextFocusDown="@+id/edttextpinnumber"
      android:paddingLeft="10dp"
      android:typeface="monospace"
      android:singleLine="true"
      android:cursorVisible="false"
      android:textSize="@dimen/edittextsize_sub"
      android:textColorHint="@color/hint_color_light"
      android:textColor="@color/main_header"
      maskededittext:mask="(***) ***-*********" />
```

I am using this dependency:
compile 'ru.egslava:MaskedEditText:1.0.5'

Comment: Is this a native android application or Hybrid Mobile application?

Answer (score 0):

You can get readymade library for mask edittext.
https://github.com/pinball83/Masked-Edittext